# What is the most general form of this theorem: $E[X] = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} P(X > n)$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the properties section of the expected value on wikipedia we can find this short theorem:

For a non-negative integer-valued random variable $X: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{N}_0$,

$E[X] = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} P(X > n)$

I remember this theorem in a more general version used for Lebesgue integrals with some general measure. The problem is that it does not have a commanding name and I can't find the general version anymore. I used this version to calculate the expectation of a stopping time.

So my question: What is the most general version you know and does it have some name?

Of course I would be great to have a proof of the generalization as well.

Comment: $EX=\int_0^{\infty} P(X >x) dx$ for any non-negative random variable $X$.and this is easy consequence of Fubini's Theorem, You can find  a proof in many books on Probability Theory.

Comment: Everything boils down to a special case of [Fubini or Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem).  You can also stop at some point in the middle, e.g., area/coarea formula.

Comment: @user10354138 Consequence and special case are not the same thing. 

Thanks for the reference to Fubini though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now I found the answer thanks to the reference to Fubini's theorem:

**Theorem:**
Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{A}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}_+ $ a measurable, non negative, real function. Further let $\phi: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a continuous isotone function, which is continuously differentiable at least on $\mathbb{R}_+^* = (0, \infty)$ and satisfies $\phi(0) = 0$. Then

$\int \phi \circ f d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^*} \phi(t) \mu(\{f \geq t \})\lambda(dt) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \phi'(t)\mu(\{f \geq t \})dt$

This is most general version I could find. So it is sufficient for the measure to be $\sigma$-finite; it need not be a probability measure.